# How to detect a Touch Press and Hold gesture in a WPF application?

Tags: wpf, touch, gesture

It is possible to detect a touch press and hold gesture with the MouseRightButtonDown event. Unfortunately it fires not until I release my finger from the screen. This is to late!

Does anyone have ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Hold gesture provided by [Blake.NUI toolkit](http://blakenui.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Gestures&referringTitle=Home)

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to do that in an awaitable fashion. Create a timer with specific interval. Start it when user tapped and return the method when timer elapsed. If user release the hand, return the method with false flag.

```
public static Task<bool> TouchHold(this FrameworkElement element, TimeSpan duration)
{
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> task = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    timer.Interval = duration;

    MouseButtonEventHandler touchUpHandler = delegate
    {
        timer.Stop();
        if (task.Task.Status == TaskStatus.Running)
        {
            task.SetResult(false);
        }
    };

    element.PreviewMouseUp += touchUpHandler;

    timer.Tick += delegate
    {
        element.PreviewMouseUp -= touchUpHandler;
        timer.Stop();
        task.SetResult(true);
    };

    timer.Start();
    return task.Task;
}
```

For more information, read this [post](http://wpfplayground.com/2014/08/07/touch-and-hold-gesture-awaitable/).

Comment: Hi, nice one, thank you. But I see two problems here. 1) element.PreviewMouseUp -= touchUpHandler; should be called in touchUpHandler. Otherwise every short touch adds a new event handler to element and it is detach code is not called. 2) Checking for TaskStatus.Running will never be true. The Task from TaskCompletionSource will always be in the state WaitingForActivation. Either check this or check that no one of the final states is present (Cancelled, Faulted, RanToCompletion). Kind Regards

Comment: Great solution. It its current form, it introduces a memory leak though since the PreviewMouseUp is never removed if the timer is stopped because it interval completed. If believe first setting MouseButtonEventHandler touchUpHandler = null; to separate the declaration and assignment (of touchUpHandler) and then in the first delegate adding element.PreviewMouseUp -= touchUpHandler; would fix the issue, although I didn't test.

Answer (score 3):

Great piece of code. I add just an example usage for completeness:

```
private async void btn_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  if (await TouchHold(btn, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)))
  {
    // todo: long press code goes here
  }
}
```

And from XAML:

```
<Button Name="btn" PreviewMouseDown="btn_PreviewMouseDown">Press long</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either a button or label or image, we can use the `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` for starting the delay and Stopping the delay.

For `MouseDown`,

```
    // Declaration of timer and timercount
     int timerCount = 0;
     DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();

     public myConstructor()
            {
                dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
            }

    // Mouse Down Event
     private void EnterHoldState(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
            {
                timerStarted();
            }

    //Mouse Up event
        private void ExitHoldState(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                {
                    timerStopped();
                }

// Stops the timer and resets the timer count to 0
        private void timerStopped()
        {
            dt.Stop();
            timerCount = 0;
        }

// Starts the timer and sets delayCounter function for counting the delay seconds and acts on it
        private void timerStarted()
        {
            dt.Tick += delayCounter;
            dt.Start();
            
        }

//Once delay timer reaches 2 seconds, the button navigates to nextpage.
        private void delayCounter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timerCount++;
            if (timerCount == 2)
            {
                this.NavigationService.Navigate(new nextPage());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to implement a `Button` where I needed to it to trigger after being pressed for five seconds.

To do this I created an attached behavior. I have the five seconds backed into the behavior as I did not need this configurable but easily done with a `Dependency Property` and it is hooked up to be used with a `Command` in an `MVVM` way but it could easily be changed to trigger `Click`.

```
    <Button Command="{Binding Path=ButtonCommand}">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <behaviors:PressAndHoldBehavior />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </Button>

public sealed class PressAndHoldBehavior : Behavior<Button>
{
    private DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer;

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer {Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)};
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += OnDispatcherTimerTick;
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += AssociatedObjectPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += AssociatedObjectPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        dispatcherTimer.Stop();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick -= OnDispatcherTimerTick;
        dispatcherTimer = null;
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown -= AssociatedObjectPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp -= AssociatedObjectPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp;
    }

    private void AssociatedObjectPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void AssociatedObjectPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        dispatcherTimer.Stop();
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void OnDispatcherTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AssociatedObject.Command.Execute(null);
    }
}
```